# I'm working with a dictionary of colors but muy function can use more than I have. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, colors

For context I'm working with a function that use `i` centroids, The centroids reagroups different points because I'm using a k-means clustering. I defined a dictionary of colors:

```
   colmap = {1: 'r', 2: 'g', 3: 'b', 4: "y", 5: "k", 6: "m", 7: "orange", 8: "brown", 9: "violet"}
```

My problem is that each centroid needs a color, so if there are more centroids than colors the function does not work. I'm wondering if there a dictionary of random colors with len(i) so I don't have to write a giant dictionary. The code is this:

```
i = 90
I = range(1, i+1)

centroids = {
i+1: [random.rand()*sqr_size, random.rand()*sqr_size]
for i in I}

def asignation(df, centroids):
  for i in centroids.keys():
    df['distance_from_{}'.format(i)] = (
        np.sqrt(
            (df['coord_x'] - centroids[i][0]) ** 2
            + (df['coord_y'] - centroids[i][1]) ** 2
        )
    )
  centroid_distance_cols = ['distance_from_{}'.format(i) for i in centroids.keys()]
  df['closest'] = df.loc[:, centroid_distance_cols].idxmin(axis=1)
  df['closest'] = df['closest'].map(lambda x: int(x.lstrip('distance_from_')))
  df['color'] = df['closest'].map(lambda x: colmap[x])
  return df
```

In the second to last row is my problem `colmap[x]` because there are less colors than I give the function.

```
 output >>     df['color'] = df['closest'].map(lambda x: colmap[x])
                KeyError: 76
```

Comment: Could you at least spell check your post? It is hard to understand as such, but it also has tons of misspelled words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a dictionary at all. Use the HSV color model to calculate the colors. Divide H (hue) into *n* pieces. If that's still not sufficient in amount, you can change S (saturation) and V (value) as well to get brighter or darker colors of the same hue.

This should easily give you more than 50 colors. The image below has 96, but IMHO some of them already become indistinguishable (but that might be my monitor):

[image: 96 colors]

I haven't painted the colors from my code below, but it should give you an idea on how colors can be generated:

```
import colorsys


def getColors(n: int) -> list:
    hues_needed = int(n / 3 + 1)
    HSV_colors = []
    SV_combinations = [(1, 1), (0.5, 1), (1, 0.5)]  # normal, bright, dark
    for s, v in SV_combinations:
        for x in range(hues_needed):
            HSV_colors.append((x / hues_needed, s, v))
    RGB_colors = list(map(lambda color: colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*color), HSV_colors))
    return RGB_colors


print(getColors(10))
```